# Using namespace in Unity hides functionality

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, namespaces

Using Unity 5.4 beta with Hololens, setting a class within a namespace disables some UnityEngine functionality.

If I declare a class, it all works fine. If I wrap it inside a namespace, classes don't see each other, even within the same namespace or with the using addition.

Making a class MonoBehaviour, I can drag and drop it onto a game object, if I wrap that class inside a namespace, Unity complains that it is not a MB or it has issue so it cannot be dragged.

Does anyone have similar issue? Just asking before reporting bugs since 5.4 is still beta.

Comment: Have no idea - did you try calling this classes like Namespace.MyClass ?

Comment: Can you show us an example. We're using namespaces extensively in our code and have no such issues. Do you have optional parameters anywhere by any chance?

Comment: I'll post some code tomorrow while at office but there is little about it. I have not tried to call with explicit namespace, will try that one in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out what I think is happening. Here is what I had:

```
namespace Company.Hololens
{
    public enum GazeState
    {
        None = -1, NoHit, Hit
    }
    public class CursorEventArg : EventArgs
    {

    }
    public class CursorController : Singleton<CursorController>
    {
    }
}
```

and it seems as if Unity does not like the order of class declaration. Pushing the EventArg down to the end of the script and it goes fine.

Not sure if this should be considered a bug, I have never seen any mention of class declaration order. Declaring an interface on top is fine though.

Answer (score 1):

`Classes` don't see each other because you are not importing them or accessing them through their `namespace`. To access anything in a namespace, you must `import` the `namespace` or call the `namespace` followed by the `class` name. Check below for both examples.

**Class with namespace:**

```
namespace MyANameSpace
{
    public class A
    {

    }
}
```

In order to see `class A`, you have to import it with the `using` keyword.

```
using MyANameSpace;
public class B : MonoBehaviour
{
    A a;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        a = new A();
    }
}
```

Another method is to access them directly through the `namespace`.

```
public class B : MonoBehaviour
{
    MyANameSpace.A a;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        a = new MyANameSpace.A();
    }
}
```

*If this does not solve your problem, then you have to post your code. That's likely not a bug*.

Comment: I happen to have done it properly. This is working fine in 5.3, I am using 5.4 (beta). Will check again tomorrow in case it fixed itself or I was doing something wrong but I tried in many ways and it would always end up that if one is in namespace then fine, if two classes are in different custom namespaces then issue.

Comment: @Everts I am using 5.4 (beta) too. It works. Dude post your code when you get home. You likely messed up somewhere.